# Save name value instead id on select option laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, drop-down-menu, select-options

how do i store ***name*** value instead of ***id*** when i use select option like this :

```
            <select type="text" name="jenis_hewan_id" id="jenis_hewan_id" class="form-control"> 
                    <option value="">Choose Animal</option>
                        @foreach ($jenisHewan as $data)
                            <option value="{{$data->id}}">{{$data->nama_jenis_hewan }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                </select>
```

i got error when i store that, like this :

**SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'Anjing' for column `hewan_siapa`.`ras_hewans`.`jenis_hewan_id` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `ras_hewans` (`nama_ras_hewan`, `jenis_hewan_id`) values (Sphynx, Anjing))**

but when i insert with `<option value="{{$data->id}}"` , it's work but it store as 'id' value ,not 'name' value in my database, how do i fix this?

My Controller:

```
     public function index()
    {
        $this->data['jenisHewan'] = JenisHewan::pluck('nama_jenis_hewan');
        $this->data['RasHewan'] = RasHewan::paginate(5);
        // $this->data['getParentOption'] = JenisHewan::where('id')->pluck('nama_jenis_hewan');
    
        $this->data['sortDataByName'] = RasHewan::latest('nama_ras_hewan');
    
        return view('admin.rashewan.ras-hewan-index',$this->data);
    }

   

 
public function store(Request $request)
{   

    $namaJenisHewan = (String)$request->jenis_hewan_id;

    $validator = $request->validate([
        'nama_ras_hewan'        => 'required|string|min:3',
        'jenis_hewan_id'        => 'required|string|',
        'parent_ras_jenis_hewan'=> 'string', 
    ], [
        'nama_ras_hewan.required' => 'Ras Hewan tidak boleh kosong',
        ]
    );

    

    $rasHewans = new RasHewan();
    $rasHewans->nama_ras_hewan = $request->nama_ras_hewan;
    $rasHewans->jenis_hewan_id = $namaJenisHewan;
    $rasHewans->parent_ras_jenis_hewan = $request->parent_ras_jenis_hewan;

    // $rasHewan = New RasHewan;
    // $rasHewan->parent_ras_jenis_hewan = $request->$getParentOption;
    // $rasHewan->save();


    RasHewan::create($validator);   
    
    return dd($validator);
    // if(validator()) {
    //     return redirect()->route('rashewan.index')
    //                      ->with('success', 'Data '.$request->nama_ras_hewan .' telah selesai dibuat.');
    // } else {
    //     return redirect()->route('rashewan.index')->with('error','Data gagal dibuat');
    // }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with controller.First remove this line below

```
 RasHewan::create($validator);
```

and then modify `RasHewan` like below

```
  $rasHewans = new RasHewan();
    $rasHewans->nama_ras_hewan = $request->nama_ras_hewan;
    $rasHewans->jenis_hewan_id = $namaJenisHewan;
    $rasHewans->parent_ras_jenis_hewan = $request->parent_ras_jenis_hewan;
     $rasHewans->save();
```

Comment: jenis_hewan_id in my RasHewanTable was unsignedBigInteger, it's define as foreign key with JenisHewan table

Comment: yeah man, is BigInteger only for integer value ?

Comment: then y are you converting to string.You can remove string from this  $namaJenisHewan = (String)$request->jenis_hewan_id;  remove (string)

Comment: @DaffaRakaMahendra Yes. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html

Comment: @JohnLobo i just want to try use converting to string and it still appear problemm, when i remove (String) , still error with SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value:........

Comment: Schema::create('ras_hewans', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nama_ras_hewan')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('jenis_hewan_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('parent_ras_jenis_hewan')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            
            $table->foreign('jenis_hewan_id')->references('id')->on('jenis_hewans')
                  ->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

        });

Comment: try once remove  RasHewan::create($validator) and add save to this like $rasHewans = new RasHewan();
    $rasHewans->nama_ras_hewan = $request->nama_ras_hewan;
    $rasHewans->jenis_hewan_id = $namaJenisHewan;
    $rasHewans->parent_ras_jenis_hewan = $request->parent_ras_jenis_hewan;
$rasHewans->save();

Comment: it's still same error, or maybe i could at 1 column after jenis_hewan_id to define jenis_hewan name and use jenis_hewan_id to get id?

Comment: te id itself .dont use my annwer. i have changed to name

Comment: ok thanks for your time & answer man, may god bless you and have a nice day

Comment: what is the data type of 'jenis_hewan_id' in your table? seems like this is expecting integer and you're trying to push string there

Comment: @MehediHassan it's bigInteger bcs that field i set to foreign key with other table

Comment: @JohnLobo it's not error ,but when i dd($query) , it's appear as "[ ]" value

Comment: show code where you did dd($query).need full method code

Comment: can't put it there, too long, what's your social media?

Comment: create online sandbox